Google Navigation SDK Android stops multiple destination route in the first waypoint
I wrote this code, which should take the user to all waypoints then end the route, but instead it ends when arriving at first point.
Video of issue:
https://youtube.com/shorts/MiCmPkNRTkI
As you can see in the video the route ends right when arriving to first waypoint.
Reference:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/navigation/android-sdk?hl=pt-br
My Code:
private fun navigateWithWaypoints(waypoints: List<Local>) {
    if (waypoints.isEmpty()) {
      showToast("Nenhum waypoint disponível para navegação")
      return
    }

    val waypointObjects = waypoints.mapNotNull { local ->
      try {
        // Criar um Waypoint usando as coordenadas do Local
        val (latitude, longitude) = local.coordinates.split(",").map { it.trim().toDouble() }
        Waypoint.builder().setLatLng(latitude, longitude).build()
      } catch (e: Exception) {
        Log.e("NavViewActivity", "Erro ao criar waypoint para ${local.name}: ${e.message}")
        null // Ignorar waypoints inválidos
      }
    }

    if (waypointObjects.isEmpty()) {
      showToast("Nenhum waypoint válido encontrado")
      return
    }

    // Usar o Navigator para configurar os waypoints e iniciar a navegação
    withNavigatorAsync {
      val pendingRoute: ListenableResultFuture<RouteStatus>  = navigator.setDestinations(waypointObjects);

      pendingRoute.setOnResultListener { code ->
        when (code) {
          RouteStatus.OK -> {
            actionBar?.hide() // Ocultar barra de ações
            navigator.setAudioGuidance(Navigator.AudioGuidance.VOICE_ALERTS_AND_GUIDANCE)

            // Simular navegação (para testes/debug)
            if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
              navigator.simulator.simulateLocationsAlongExistingRoute(
                SimulationOptions().speedMultiplier(5f)
              )
            }

            // Iniciar a navegação
            navigator.startGuidance()
          }
              RouteStatus.ROUTE_CANCELED -> showToast("Navegação cancelada")
              RouteStatus.NO_ROUTE_FOUND,
              RouteStatus.NETWORK_ERROR -> showToast("Erro ao determinar rota: $code")
              else -> showToast("Erro iniciando navegação: $code")
            }
        }
    }
}

I tried GPT, searching online and the documentation
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/navigation/android-sdk/multi-destination?hl=pt-br
but didn't get the answer.
Thanks in advance.

Nobody answered to the question so I kept on it, and later on discovered a mistake I had made when coding the registerNavigationListeners function.
private fun registerNavigationListeners() {
    withNavigatorAsync {
      arrivalListener = Navigator.ArrivalListener {
        // Check if there are remaining waypoints
        val remainingWaypoints = waypoints.count()
        var indexCurrent = 0

        if (remainingWaypoints == 0) {
          showToast("ROTA FINALIZADA")

          // ==>>>  HERE WAS THE ERROR, THIS WAS NOT COVERED BY
          // ==>>>  AN IF STATEMENT WHICH MADE NAVIGATION STOP WITHOUT 
          // ==>>>  ACTUALLY FINISHING THE ROUTE.
          navigator.clearDestinations()

          // Stop simulating vehicle movement
          if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            navigator.simulator?.unsetUserLocation()
          }
        } else {
          // Continue to the next waypoint
          showToast("PEGAR: ${waypoints[indexCurrent].name.uppercase()}")
          indexCurrent += 1
          navigator.continueToNextDestination()
          waypoints.removeAt(0)
        }
      }
      navigator.addArrivalListener(arrivalListener)

      routeChangedListener = Navigator.RouteChangedListener {
        showToast("SAIU DO TRAJETO")
      }
      navigator.addRouteChangedListener(routeChangedListener)
    }
  }

Thats it, just a little mistake I had made in another piece of the code.
